# Refresh of openjpa entity throwing exception - but this context still has a cached version

Tags: java, openjpa

This is the persist method I am calling to insert an entity. the refresh method throws this exception `The instance of type "class com.kabadi.persistence.beans.User" with oid "0" no longer exists in the data store.  This may mean that you deleted the instance in a separate transaction, but this context still has a cached version.`

```
@Transactional
public void persist(T entity) {
    this.entityManager.persist(entity);
    this.flush();
    this.refresh(entity);
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User
{
    @Basic
    @Column(name="created_time", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP", nullable=false)
    private Date createdTime;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable=false, length=64)
    private String password;

    @Basic
    @Column(length=20)
    private String phone;

    @Basic
    @Column(name="updated_time", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP", nullable=false)
    private Date updatedTime;

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id", columnDefinition="INT")
    private int userId;

   @OneToMany(targetEntity=com.kabadi.persistence.beans.UserOrder.class,   mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Set userOrders = new HashSet ();

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable=false, length=64)
    private String username;

    // setters and getters
}
```

This driving me crazy. Any help please????

Comment: Can you post the Entity that you are persisting / flushing / refreshing? Also, why are you calling the refresh operation?

Comment: @Rick. User entity posted. I am calling refresh because I want to entity back to the user who created it.

Comment: Is this.flush() calling em.flush()?